# set object method Parent

Tags: c#, object, parent

i have:

```
object[] obj = new object[button1, label1]; //
object parent; // some Panel
```

i need

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++) 
   obj[i].Parent = parent;
```

**How to get it?**

Comment: If this is C# you should tag it C# and you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I think that first line might be wrong, are you trying to declare an array of objects, e.g. 'object[] obj = new object[] { button1, label1 };'?

Answer (score 1):

```
var controls = new Control[] { button1, label1 };
Control parent = ...;

foreach (Control control in controls)
{
    control.Parent = parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal .NET parent/child relationships are created like this:

```
parent.Controls.Add(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object[] obj = new object[] { button1, label1 }; // create array of objects
object parent; // some Panel


for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
{ 
   ((Control)obj[i]).Parent = parent;
}
```